# Fastest way to calculate all the even squares from 1 to n?

Tags: c, factors

I did this in c :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
 int n,i;

 scanf("%d", &n);

 for(i=2;i<=n;i=i+2)
 {
   if((i*i)%2==0 && (i*i)<= n)
      printf("%d \n",(i*i));
 }
 return 0;
}
```

What would be a better/faster approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: (i*i)%2==0 if and only if i%2==0, since even*even=even and odd*odd=odd. therefore, you can remove the (i*i)%2==0 from the if, and save the computition time of i*i.

Comment: You probably want to use unsigned integers and you can bound your loop by taking the square root of N.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me illustrate not only a fast solution, but also how to derive it. Start with a fast way of listing all squares and work from there (pseudocode):

```
max = n*n
i = 1
d = 3

while i < max:
    print i
    i += d
    d += 2
```

So, starting from 4 and listing only even squares:

```
max = n*n
i = 4
d = 5

while i < max:
    print i
    i += d
    d += 2
    i += d
    d += 2
```

Now we can shorten that mess on the end of the while loop:

```
max = n*n
i = 4
d = 5

while i < max:
    print i
    i += 2 + 2*d
    d += 4
```

Note that we are constantly using `2*d`, so it's better to just keep calculating that:

```
max = n*n
i = 4
d = 10

while i < max:
    print i
    i += 2 + d
    d += 8
```

Now note that we are constantly adding `2 + d`, so we can do better by incorporating this into `d`:

```
max = n*n
i = 4
d = 12

while i < max:
    print i
    i += d
    d += 8
```

Blazing fast. It only takes two additions to calculate each square.

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution. The only suggestions I would make would be:

- Put the `(i*i)<=n` as the middle clause of your for loop, then it's checked earlier and you break out of the loop sooner.
- You don't need to check and see if `(i*i)%2==0`, since 'i' is always positive and a positive squared is always positive.
- With those two changes in mind you can get rid of the if statement in your for loop and just print.

Answer (score 1):

Square of even is even. So, you really do not need to check it again. Following is the code, I would suggest:

```
for (i = 2; i*i <= n; i+=2)
     printf ("%d\t", i*i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The largest value for `i` in your loop should be the floor of the square root of `n`.

The reason is that the square of any `i` (integer) larger than this will be greater than `n`. So, if you make this change, you don't need to check that `i*i <= n`.

Also, as others have pointed out, there is no point in checking that `i*i` is **even** since the square of all even numbers is even.

And you are right in ignoring **odd** `i` since for any odd `i`, `i*i` **is odd**.

**Your code with the aforementioned changes follows:**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

int main () 
{
    int n,i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for( i = 2; i <= (int)floor(sqrt(n)); i = i+2 ) {       
        printf("%d \n",(i*i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```